How to update file content in MS Graph without creating versions
Is it possible to update the content of a file using MS Graph without creating a new version?  We are making minor updates to many, many files and not wanting to take a storage hit.
Here is what we have tried:
*** Looking at file versions of foo.txt in Folder "Graph Testing"
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<DRIVE_ID>/root:/Graph Testing:/children/foo.txt/versions/?$select=id,lastModifiedDateTime,size

Response:
{
    "id": "1.0",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-12-06T15:26:24Z",
    "size": 8
}

*** Replace the file with new content
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/ <DRIVE_ID>/root:/Graph Testing/foo.txt:/content?@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=replace
Request Headers: Content-Type = text/plain
Request Body: My File's New Content

*** Verify on Sharepoint that the file has the new content sucessfully
*** Look at the versions again
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/ <DRIVE_ID>/root:/Graph Testing:/children/foo.txt/versions/?$select=id,lastModifiedDateTime,size

Response:
{
    "id": "2.0",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-12-10T21:59:31Z",
    "size": 21
},
{
    "id": "1.0",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-12-06T15:26:24Z",
    "size": 8
}

We have also played with @microsoft.graph.conflictBehaviors, and confirmed the settings are taking effect (if we set it to rename or error, those behaviors do happen).  But we have been unable to replace the current document without triggering creation of a new version.
Is this even possible?  Or are we going to be forced to trying to delete the previous version after we upload the new content?
